# Runtime error 438 when InvokeMember clicking on VB6

Tags: vb6, error-handling, runtime, runtime-error

In VB6, I am unable to click `skip_ad_button`. I get  the Runtime error:

> runtime error 438 :object does not support this property error

What is the alternative to

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_ad_button").InvokeMember ("Click")
```

in VB6?

Comment: this is vb.net can you please tranform the code to vb6

Comment: are you trying to call click event of button on webpage?

Answer (score 1):

The runtime error is telling you that one of the objects you are using does not have the method you are calling. The possibilities are:

1. WebBrowser1 does not have a Document property
2. Document does not have a GetElementById property
3. The object returned by GetElementById("skip_ad_button") does not have an InvokeMember property

Without knowing your exact object structure it would be very difficult to give a definitively correct answer. Reading [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may give you a starting point but you need to do some research.